# Trouble getting Flash Player plugin to run under Chromium

Tags: raspbian-jessie, video, chromium, plugins

I have just set up a Raspberry Pi 3 model B, which came with the "Boolean Box" for my daughter. Everything worked fine, but the browser that was on the SD card did not run Flash, which would be necessary to make full use of the Scratch website with all the programming examples for kids. Therefore, I downloaded and installed the Chromium browser, which supposedly comes with a version of Flash Player plugin suitable for the Raspberry. The broswer itself works, however, I am unable to get the Flash plugin running, and I'm not sure if it was actually included in that download. I'm a Raspberry and Linux novice, and haven't used Unix commands for over 20 years. Any advice is appreciated.